# Link of react-router-dom not changing the routes (ReactRouter6)

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

A simple SPA with a sidebar.

For now, I should only have 2 pages/routes: 1) Dashboard in "/", and 2) Team in "/team".
Try the app vercel link here: https://react-admin-dashboard-eight-pi.vercel.app/team

Using Link from ReactRouter6, for some reason, the routing is not working. Clicking on the sidebar menu does not trigger any routing changes.
What am I doing wrong here?

full codes here: https://github.com/windyzhang777/react-admin-dashboard/blob/main/src/App.jsx

// App.jsx

```
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

<div className="app">
  <Sidebar /> {/* -------------------------------- has all the Links */}
  <main className="content">
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} /> {/* ---- home route */}
      <Route path="/team" element={<Team />} /> {/* ----- team route */}
    </Routes>
  </main>
</div>
```

// Sidebar.jsx

```
import { Menu, MenuItem, Sidebar as ProSidebar } from "react-pro-sidebar";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Sidebar() {
  const [isCollapsed, setIsCollapsed] = useState(false);
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState("Dashboard");

  return (
    <Box>
      <ProSidebar collapsed={isCollapsed}>
        <Menu>
          {/* MENU ITEMS */}
          <Box>
            <MenuItem
              active={selected === "Dashboard"}
              onClick={() => setSelected("Dashboard")}
            >
              <Typography>{"Dashboard"}</Typography>
              <Link to={"/"} /> {/* ---------------------- home route */}
            </MenuItem>

            <MenuItem
              active={selected === "Manage Team"}
              onClick={() => setSelected("Manage Team")}
            >
              <Typography>{"Manage Team"}</Typography>
              <Link to={"/team"} /> {/* ------------------ team route */}
            </MenuItem>
          </Box>
        </Menu>
      </ProSidebar>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<Link>` elements do not have any children or content, so they are 0 by 0 pixels, which makes them too small to click.

You can put the labels inside the `<Link>` elements, or better yet, use React Pro Sidebar's Router integration using MenuItem's `component` prop, as described [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pro-sidebar):

```
    <MenuItem component={<Link to="/calendar" />}> Calendar</MenuItem>
```